# Cannot select multiple items in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

My C# ASP.NET web site has a weird problem.

I set a selected value for a dropdownlilst based on a value from a stored procedure output parameter like this:

```
this.myDropDown.SelectedValue = cmd.Parameters["@SourceID"].Value.ToString().Trim();
```

For some reason, I get a "Cannot have multiple items selected in a dropdownlist" error on this line of code. I've stepped through the code and searched for other references to this dropdownlist, commented the references out, and tried again.

Nope, still doesn't work.

The only way the page works is if I comment out the above line of code. Any ideas why this would be a problem?

SourceID is always an integer and exists in the list of selections. I've verified (by stepping through the code) that the selectedValue is always numeric, and never changes between the time this line executes and the time the page finishes loading.

Thoughts?

Comment: Check the datasource of your dropdownlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would occur if you had two items in the `DropDownList` with the same `Value`.

Comment: In a couple minutes I can accept the answer that led me to the solution...the weird thing is it was duplicated items in the list, but it wasn't the selected item. (Weird but true) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

If you do mean to select multiple items, you need to use ListBox control with `SelectionMode="Multiple"` set.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 items with the same value.

**You can solve it:**

1) Find Items by value to list.

2) Get first item index.

3) Select item by index.