# How to select a month in drop down list according current month upon page load?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, drop-down-menu, pageload

I would like to write the code such that when I run my program, the Month Drop Down List is automatically selected according to date.time.now. month when I load the page.

I have tried the code below but I get an error saying:

> " Cannot have multiple items selected in a Drop Down List".

I am unsure of what this means since I have no other items selected.

(My Month drop down list currently has list items from Jan to Dec denoted with the index 0-11)

```
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;

        for (int i = 0; i < MonthDropDownList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (month == 1) //Jan
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[0].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 2) //Feb
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[1].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 3) //March
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[2].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 4) //April
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[3].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 5) //May
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[4].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 6) //June
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[5].Selected = true;

            }
            else if (month == 7) //July
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[6].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 8) //Aug
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[7].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 9) //Sept
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[8].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 10) //Oct
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[9].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 11) //Nov
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[10].Selected = true;
            }
            else if (month == 12) //Dec
            {
                MonthDropDownList.Items[11].Selected = true;
            }

        }
```

What do I have to change in my code to solve this issue? Or is there another solution I can use to automatically select the current month?

Comment: why dont you use switch instead of if-else? it makes your code more readable.

Comment: You don't need for statement, conditional(if else) is enough

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yeah that's a possible method as well but my code seems to be returning an error.

Comment: @DikaArtaKaruniai I have removed the for statement but my program still won't run.

Comment: delete all your if-else and for... just use what Mairaj Ahmad answered. you have index as month. you have the month. so use it as index. dont use if-else conditions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot select multiple items in a dropdownlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322373/cannot-select-multiple-items-in-a-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do like this

```
 MonthDropDownList.SelectedIndex = month - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

in your page_load event if you build your dropdown value as month number

```
MonthDropDownList.SelectedValue = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
```

or you can use  as you did in your code

```
MonthDropDownList.SelectedIndex= DateTime.Now.Month -1;
```

I use always SelectedValue  because index not reliable in my company :)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid for loop in your code.

You can use like this also
**c#**

MonthDropDownList.SelectedValue = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

**Code behind**

```
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Jan</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Feb</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Apr</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">May</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Jun</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="7">July</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="8">Aug</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="9">Sep</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="10">Oct</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="11">Nov</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="12">Dec</asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need for statement, conditional(if else) is enough

Comment: this should be posted as comment. its not answer